# NSDate Formatter time zone issue

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter, nstimezone

I have a NSString like this."10/28/2014  9:20 PM PDT".I have to convert exactly  this to NSDate.But on conversion,the time zone is converted to IST.This is what i tried.

```
departTime=@"10/28/2014  9:20 PM PDT"  
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a zzz"];
NSDate *departTimedate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:departTime];
```

This is what i am getting on converting to NSDate: "2014-10-29 04:40:00 +0000"

Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: Don't set the timezone on the date formatter. The timezone will be extracted from the date string.

Comment: @rmaddy i tried that too..

Comment: What you are seeing is correct. When you log the date, it is logged in UTC time (notice the +0000). PDT is currently UTC-7. So 10/28/2014 9:20PM PDT is the same as 10/29/2014 4:20AM UTC. What did you expect to see?

Comment: i want it in the PDT time zone.exactly like this "10/28/2014 9:20PM PDT"

Comment: That's not how it works. `NSDate` has no timezone. It's just an offset from an epoch. If you want to output the date in a specific format and timezone, then setup an `NSDateFormatter` to convert the `NSDate` to an `NSString` in the desired format.

Comment: Even the date is changed.the date should be 27 instead of 29.right?

Comment: No. As I said, the output your are seeing is correct.

Comment: okay.will do like this